# WebGL UVs scaling differently between Windows Phone and Windows apps

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, webgl

I was working on a WebGL application, and it was running fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and a Windows 8 app. However, when I tried porting it to a Windows Phone app using the same code, the texture reads appeared to be messed up, seemingly multiplying all the UVs for no reason.

None of the code or UV data changed between the platforms, and the phone runs IE 11, the same version I tested on my laptop. The Windows 8 App project was the same project as the phone, with the code and texture data shared between them.

Does windows phone have issues with WebGL, despite saying it supports it, or is there some change that needs to be made to handle the UVs or textures correctly? In case it helps, I found it was about a factor of 2.8~2.9 off in both directions. The vertex shader I used was:

```
    precision mediump float;
    attribute vec2 a_pos;
    attribute vec2 a_uv;
    attribute vec4 a_color;
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;
    varying vec4 v_color;
    varying vec2 v_uv;
    void main() {
      vec2 clip = a_pos * u_resolution - 1.0;
      gl_Position = vec4(clip * vec2(1, -1), 0.0, 1.0);
      v_color = a_color;
      v_uv = a_uv;
    }
```

And the fragment shader:

```
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D u_image;
    varying vec4 v_color;
    varying vec2 v_uv;
    void main() {
      vec4 imgColor = texture2D(u_image, v_uv);
      gl_FragColor = imgColor * v_color;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what are the actual indices? Phones have limited precision.

Comment: An example UV list for an image is: 
[0.822021484375,0.060302734375,0.846435546875,0.060302734375,0.822021484375,0.079833984375,0.822021484375,0.079833984375,0.846435546875,0.060302734375,0.846435546875,0.079833984375]
If it was slightly off, I would understand precision, but it is a multiplied factor off.